# Dlink DWA-556 Access point fails to start on 2.6.35-25 while 2.6.35-24 works. How can I do this with >2.6.35-24?

Tags: kernel, wireless-access-point, hostap

I'm using hostapd to run an access point with a Dlink DWA-556 wireless N card. However, I can no longer get it to start when I use kernels greater than 2.6.35-24. Here's a log where I ran the `uname -a&&hostapd -c <configfile>` on the different kernel versions.

```
Linux erikbandersen 2.6.35-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 02:41:37 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
ctrl_interface_group=0  
Opening raw packet socket for ifindex 248
BSS count 1, BSSID mask ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (0 bits)
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=21 enc_capa=0xf
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
HT40: control channel: 2  secondary channel: 6
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x2
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x6
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x6
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x6
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Passive scanning not supported
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 2  Frequency: 2417 MHz
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
Using interface wlan1 with hwaddr 1c:bd:b9:d5:e8:3c and ssid 'erikbandersen.com/freewifi'
wlan1: Setup of interface done.
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
Malformed netlink message: len=436 left=256 plen=420
256 extra bytes in the end of netlink message
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
mgmt::auth
authentication: STA=3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=1 status_code=0 wep=0
  New STA
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f IEEE 802.11: authentication OK (open system)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-AUTHENTICATE.indication(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f, OPEN_SYSTEM)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f)
authentication reply: STA=3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f auth_alg=0 auth_transaction=2 resp=0 (IE len=0)
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::auth cb
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f IEEE 802.11: authenticated
mgmt::assoc_req
association request: STA=3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f capab_info=0x421 listen_interval=10
Validating WMM IE: OUI 00:50:f2  OUI type 2  OUI sub-type 0  version 1  QoS info 0x0
HT: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f HT Capabilities Info: 0x102c
handle_assoc STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f - no greenfield, num of non-gf stations 1
handle_assoc STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f - 20 MHz HT, num of 20MHz HT STAs 1
hostapd_ht_operation_update current operation mode=0x0
hostapd_ht_operation_update new operation mode=0x7 changes=2
  new AID 1
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f IEEE 802.11: association OK (aid 1)
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::assoc_resp cb
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f IEEE 802.11: associated (aid 1)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-ASSOCIATE.indication(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f RADIUS: starting accounting session 4DAC8224-00000000
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::action cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
MGMT (TX callback) ACK
mgmt::proberesp cb
Signal 2 received - terminating
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-DEAUTHENTICATE.indication(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f, 1)
wlan1: STA 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f MLME: MLME-DELETEKEYS.request(3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f)
Removing station 3c:4a:92:0e:41:2f
hostapd_ht_operation_update current operation mode=0x7
hostapd_ht_operation_update new operation mode=0x0 changes=2
Flushing old station entries
Deauthenticate all stations
```

.

```
Linux erikbandersen 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
ctrl_interface_group=0  
Opening raw packet socket for ifindex 248
BSS count 1, BSSID mask ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (0 bits)
SIOCGIWRANGE: WE(compiled)=22 WE(source)=21 enc_capa=0xf
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=27 dBm
HT40: control channel: 2  secondary channel: 6
RATE[0] rate=10 flags=0x2
RATE[1] rate=20 flags=0x6
RATE[2] rate=55 flags=0x6
RATE[3] rate=110 flags=0x6
RATE[4] rate=60 flags=0x0
RATE[5] rate=90 flags=0x0
RATE[6] rate=120 flags=0x0
RATE[7] rate=180 flags=0x0
RATE[8] rate=240 flags=0x0
RATE[9] rate=360 flags=0x0
RATE[10] rate=480 flags=0x0
RATE[11] rate=540 flags=0x0
Passive scanning not supported
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 2  Frequency: 2417 MHz
Could not set channel for kernel driver
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
```

My wireless card is listed as `02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5008 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)` by lspci. Am I doing it wrong and there's a new way of doing it? I'm holding off upgrading to Natty because of this. What changed between the versions that would cause this? Should I report it as a bug?

By the way, here's the version of hostapd and my hostapd.conf

```
apt-cache policy hostapd
hostapd:
  Installed: 1:0.6.10-2
  Candidate: 1:0.6.10-2
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.6.10-2 0
        500 http://mirrors.xmission.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

[Pastebin of hostapd.conf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/653276/)

Comment: What version of hostapd are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a good look around for some info on this problem it looks like a problem with the version of hostapd in the Ubuntu currently 0.6.1

I refer to this mailing list which confirms the bug and provides a solution

[ath9k+hostapd = "Could not set DTIM period for kernel driver](http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2010-February/021118.html)

The solution proposed is not surprising upgrade to 0.7.3 currently as whatever [Kernel update](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_25) (check the networking section) in 2.6.25 was patched in the new version. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get this in Ubuntu just yet however the version slated for inclusion in Oneric 11.10 will be the new version in the mean time you will have to compile from source or alternatively you could use alien to convert an rpm as one has been built for Fedora 15 Here [Hostapd at pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/package/hostapd)

hope this helps solve your problem

Comment: It fixed it. Thanks! I ended up using the Debian packages at http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/hostapd & http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libssl1.0.0 and they work great. I had to take the bridge part out of my config as the wireless interface was no longer part of a bridge.

Comment: Sweet it was kind of like an investigation finding out what was causing the problem and finding a possible solution (been watching too much House lately) that is cool glad I was able to help